# How to collect specific text to another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a file like this image. In cell `B1` before `-` (hyphen) is fabrication after then fabric color `- POINCIANA -` between `-` (hyphen).
Now I want to collect fabrication in the next cell `C1` & color on `D1`. How can I do this? If anyone can do this, please help me.!

I want like below image:

[image: I want like below image.]

Comment: Could it be that you are talking about some spreadsheet application you are working with? We can only _guess_ that, you really should mention that and tag your question accordingly. Now way to get an answer without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Excel.

In cell `C1`:

```
=LEFT($B1,SEARCH(" - ",$B1))
```

In cell `D1`:

```
=MID($B1,LEN($C1)+LEN(" - "),SEARCH(" - ",$B1,LEN($C1)+LEN(" - "))-LEN($C1)-LEN(" - "))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks as though you could use Text to Columns with `-` as the delimiter. If so and you want to preserve your ColumnB data 'as is' be sure to make a copy of it first. But this is untested as I am not proposing to retype all your data!

Select ColumnB (make sure there are columns available to the right), Data  > Data Tools - Text to Columns and hopefully 'home and dry'.